# Replace characters in the xml and also apply templates after replacement of string using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

We would like to replace the some special characters in the whole xml file and also apply some templates to the xml using XSLT 1.0.

For example Please consider the following xml file,

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?>
<UserDetails>
<Name>RamesÒ</Name>
<RollNumber>101</RollNumber>
<Contact>
<ContactAddress>
12 StreetnÒ,
LondonÒ
</ContactAddress>
<Email>Remaesh@gmail.com</Email>
<PhoneNumber>123566595656</PhoneNumber>
</Contact>
</UserDetails>
```

To the above xml file I need to apply a style sheet which should replace all "Ò" with "*" in the whole xml file and will return the result like below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Candidate>
<Address>
<ContactAddress>
12 Streetn*
London*
</ContactAddress>
</Address>
<Name>Rames*</Name>
</Candidate>
```

I have tried the below XSLT but not able to get the expected output,

### XSLT

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:preserve-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vAllowedSymbols"
        select="'@1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 
        '"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,translate(.,$vAllowedSymbols, '*'),'*')"/>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Candidate>
            <Name>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//Name" />
            </Name>
            <Address>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//ContactAddress" />
            </Address>              
        </Candidate>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ContactAddress">
        <xsl:value-of select= "." />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Name">
        <xsl:value-of select= "." />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Output:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Candidate>
<Name>RamesÃ</Name>
<Address>
12 StreetnÃ,
LondonÃ
</Address>
</Candidate>
```

I have tried to translate the character while selecting the value like,

```
<xsl:template match="ContactAddress">
        <xsl:value-of select= "translate(.,translate(.,$vAllowedSymbols, '*'),'*')" />
    </xsl:template>
```

It will result in expected output. But this is sample xml file but in real we have xml file with numerous nodes which may contains characters that needs to replaced by "*". Applying translate function while selecting values is huge process .

Can any one please guide me how to replace the characters in the xml file and then apply the templates to get the expected response using XSLT 1.0?.

### Expected Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Candidate>
<Address>
<ContactAddress>
12 Streetn*
London*
</ContactAddress>
</Address>
<Name>Rames*</Name>
</Candidate>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The cleanest way to do this is to run a pipeline of two separate XSLT transformations. This keeps your code modular and reusable. There are many tools that allow you to run transformations in a pipeline, for example XProc, Ant, xmlsh, Java/.NET APIs, or simply a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

Put the replace into a text() template:

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select= "translate(.,translate(.,$vAllowedSymbols, '*'),'*')" />
</xsl:template>
```

and the on all places where you need it apply that one e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="ContactAddress">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try it. But in our case we have to replace this things in more places of our XSLT.   Would it be possible to replace the string at first and apply templates ?

Comment: Does your processor support exslt:node-set function? Then you could do an identity-transform (search here for several examples), just matching the text() with the template from above, store the result in a variable, say textclean, and then apply your normal formatting `<xsl:apply-templates select="exslt:node-set($textclean)"/>`  though not even sure if you need the node-set function around. However, for the identity transform, you should use templates with a (e.g.) mode="cleantext" so that the templates are called before

Comment: @Dinesh Why does the order matter? If you have a template matching text(), it will be applied to **all** text nodes in your input - unless you explicitly override it (for example, by using  `<xsl:value-of select= "." />` instead of `<xsl:apply-templates/>` as you have done in your original stylesheet.